# How to edit a pre-existing model to add a newly created associated class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

I have an apartment object on a live application. I decided to add an associated amenities object for each apartment to describe which amenities the apartment has.
*amenity model shows*

```
class Amenity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :apartment
end
```

*apartment model show*

```
class Apartment < ApplicationRecord
has_one :amenity, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :amenity
end
```

Creating new apartment with the associated amenities works well
*apartment controller shows*

```
  def new
   @apartment = Apartment.new
   @apartment.build_amenity
  end
```

Once the apartment is created with the amenities, the amenities can be easily edited
*apartment controller show*

```
def edit; end
```

However, for existing apartment, the edit form does not show the amenities to be filled (most likely because there is no pre-created amenities associated with pre-existing apartment). I tried to change the edit action in the controller as follow

```
def edit
 @apartment = Apartment.find_or_initialize_by(params[:id])
end
```

```
def edit
 @apartment = Apartment.find_or_create_by(params[:id])
end
```

But both option does not enable the form to show up. The form works well when creating brand new apartment with associated amenities so there is something in the controller missing (an equivalent of @apartment.build_amenity in the edit controller that would instantiate a new amenity object associated with pre-existing apartment that I want to edit). Could you please help me resolve this issue?

Here is the form code (quite basic)

```
<%= form.fields_for :amenity, @apartment.amenity do |p| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For editing the existed `apartment` you can use `includes` to preload `amenity`

```rb
def edit
 @apartment = Apartment.includes(:amenity).find_or_initialize_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

in form

```rb
<%= form.fields_for :amenity, (@apartment.amenity || @apartment.build_amenity) do |p| %>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This line gives me an error: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer LINE 1: SELECT "apartments".* FROM "apartments" WHERE (47) LIMIT $1 ^ - note that the ameniy model is a list of field (towel, irons, etc.) that have boolean value (true if the amenity is available, false if the amenity is not available).

Comment: @Bastien my bad, i copy your code :D, maybe `id: params[:id]` work.

Comment: @Bastien also update in form to check if amenty nil then build the association

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding false as the default value directly into the table

```
  create_table "amenities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "towels", default: false
    t.boolean "bed_linen", default: false
    t.boolean "toilet_paper", default: false
    t.boolean "soap", default: false
    ...
```

Having false value by default instead of nil enabled the form to appear.